# update multiple views on multiple dialogs connected to a single data model

Tags: python, model-view-controller, model, pyqt, qcombobox

i have Two forms with two views connected to the same dataModel class, but when i change data on one form it does not change on the other.

i am trying to get a comboBox on several different dialogs/forms to get updated when the underlying data changes from another dialog/form.

here is my code:

```
class Model(QStringListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        data = QStringList()
        data << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five"
        self.setStringList(data)


class Form_2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.combo = QListView()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.listView = QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        self.form2_button = QPushButton("Open Form_2")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listView)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.form2_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.form2_button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.form_2)

    def form_2(self):
        self.ft = Form_2()
        self.ft.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form_1()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Different views based on the same model should display the same values when data from the model is modified from any view, you probably are using the model/view framework incorrectly, please post a simplified version of your code to help in identifying where your issue is.

Comment: `QStandardItemModel` already has a method called `setData`. Your `setData` method is probably causing some kind of conflict. To get further help you should also post the part of code in which you are actually using the model and the view. Since you are working with databases, consider using `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSqlTableModel` instead.

Comment: i know that the setData is not properly implemented, but i only did that because i tried without it the model got populated, but i had no way of repopulating it. and i also tried several other models, like QAbstractTableModel, QSqlTableModel QSqlQueryModel, i tried them directly on both forms, not through creating my own class.. it all worked fine getting the initial data, but i had now way of refreshing the combo to get the new data. i am at loss here.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think you could build a simple example that works? the idea is 2 independent forms, using the same model and both getting the changes in the model when its being changed by only one.

Comment: is it possible that the model only updates the views of the same instance but not a view from another instance?  i added what i tried on the bottom of my post, look above.

Comment: Each time you use `self.model = Model()` you are creating a different instance of your model, so changes applied to one of them won't be reflected on the other. To prevent this you could, for example, initiate the dialog with your model as an argument. I'll update my answer to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how multiple views based on the same model update themselves when the any of those views is modified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, modelSource, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.setModel(modelSource)

        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(self)
        self.listView.setModel(modelSource)
        self.listView.setModelColumn(0)

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setModel(modelSource)
        self.comboBox.setModelColumn(1)

        self.layoutGrid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.listView, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.tableView, 1, 1, 1, 1)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    _dialogs = []
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.modelSource = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for rowNumber in range(3):
            items = []
            for columnNumber in range(3):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                item.setText("row: {0} column {1}".format(rowNumber, columnNumber))

                items.append(item)

            self.modelSource.appendRow(items)

        self.labelDialogs = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.labelDialogs.setText("Select a number of dialogs to create:")

        self.spinBoxDialogs = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBoxDialogs.setValue(3)

        self.pushButtonShow = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonShow.setText("Show Dialogs!")
        self.pushButtonShow.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonShow_clicked)

        self.pushButtonClose = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonClose.setText("Close Dialogs")
        self.pushButtonClose.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonClose_clicked)

        self.layoutHorizontal = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.labelDialogs)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.spinBoxDialogs)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.pushButtonShow)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.pushButtonClose)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonShow_clicked(self): 
        self._dialogs = []
        dialogsNumber = self.spinBoxDialogs.value()

        for dialogNumber in range(dialogsNumber):  
            dialog = MyDialog(self.modelSource)
            dialog.show()
            dialog.move(100, 100)

            self._dialogs.append(dialog)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonClose_clicked(self): 
        for dialog in self._dialogs:
            dialog.close()

        self._dialogs = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks @X.Jacobs. but this is on the same file, would it be possible to have an example with two separate files, or even same file but two separate dialogs?. please see my last comment.

Comment: That's something you can do by yourself. Just create as may dialogs as you want with the `tableview`, `listview` and `combobox` and `gridlayout` in my example. Then call `dialog.show()` on your created dialogs. It still won't be no different than if they were in the same widget but it might help you learning. If you still can't manage to sort it out, I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: i did, i have tried it before, didn't work. see my code in the post. i redid the post because it started to get ugly.

Comment: @JoeMicro Checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15731116/1006989), I modified it to display multiple widgets using the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ccc.larc for giving me the answer. we basically have to only use one instance of the model, it doesn't work if there several instances of the model. so you always have to pass the same instance of the model to which ever form you want it to use.

if i understand correctly this is what @X.Jacobs is saying, i m just showing my new code which is a bit more simple and could be better understood what contrasting it with my previous code (that didn't work)

so my above code just needs a minor change.

```
class Model(QStringListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        data = QStringList()
        data << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five"
        self.setStringList(data)


class Form_2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, model, parent=None): #get the model from the calling form
        super(Form_2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = model
        self.combo = QListView()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.listView = QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        self.form2_button = QPushButton("Open Form_2")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listView)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.form2_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.form2_button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.form_2)

    def form_2(self):
        self.ft = Form_2(self.model) #pass the same model to the new form
        self.ft.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form_1()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```